# javascript regular expression (end of word)

Tags: javascript, regex

I think I've a problem with regular expression:
I want a string wich can contains all the characthers in the first rounded parenthesis and eventually a [ and finally a ].
the regex is the following:

```
    var pattern = /^(([a-zA-Z0-9\.\_\-\(\)\\'\xE0\xE8\xE9\xF9\xF2\xEC\x27\,\/]\s?)*\[?([a-zA-Z0-9\.\_\-\(\)\\'\xE0\xE8\xE9\xF9\xF2\xEC\x27\,\/]\s?)*\]?)+$/;
```

the problem is that if I try to test the following string Maionese [dfvdfv]@
my program will loop forever :-|

the function that I use to test is the following:

```
//the alert doesn't works
alert(checkSpecialIngredienti("Maionese [dfvdfv]@"));
function checkSpecialIngredienti(s) {

var pattern = /^(([a-zA-Z0-9\.\_\-\(\)\\'\xE0\xE8\xE9\xF9\xF2\xEC\x27\,\/]\s?)*\[?([a-zA-Z0-9\.\_\-\(\)\\'\xE0\xE8\xE9\xF9\xF2\xEC\x27\,\/]\s?)*\]?)+$/;
if (!pattern.test(s)) {
    alert("Attenzione, il campo "+s+"" +
            " che hai inserito non va bene!" +
            "\nIn questo campo puoi inserire " +
            "lettere, numeri, lettere accentate," +
            "punteggiatura classica, singoli spazi e" +
            "\nuna sola coppia di parentesi quadre." +
            "\nRiprova!");
    return (false);
} else
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I don't see any possible way for your program to loop with this code.

Comment: I know that there is not a loop but the  program stops

Comment: Please provide a [short self-contained correct example](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates your problem. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) is a great tool for this.

Comment: I don't know how to use this tool... I try...

Comment: http://doc.jsfiddle.net/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/QXv8n/1/

Comment: That is not a SSCCE, and it doesn't demonstrate the problem. It doesn't do *anything*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running into [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) because you have nested quantifiers (`((...)*)+`), and the resulting combinatorial explosion will blow up your regex engine when the subject string cannot be matched.

Now, how to fix this? Let's first simplify your regex. There's a lot of irritating cruft in there - the following regex matches exactly the same strings as yours, but it's easier to read:

```
/^(([\w\s.,()\\\/'\xE0\xE8\xE9\xF9\xF2\xEC\x27-])*\[?([\w\s.,()\\\/'\xE0\xE8\xE9\xF9\xF2\xEC\x27-])*\]?)+$/
```

The problem now becomes clear: The `[]`s are both optional, and the `@` in your test string is not part of the allowed character range. This means that upon encountering the `@`, the regex engine needs to backtrack into the match and check if there is any other way to match the preceding part - and there are lots of ways that it has to try.

According to your specs, you don't need the final `+` at all, since you seem to be wanting to match a string that contains any of the allowed characters plus one optional, `[...]`-enclosed string of the same characters at the end. In that case, use

```
/^([\w\s.,()\\\/'\xE0\xE8\xE9\xF9\xF2\xEC\x27-]*)(\[[\w\s.,()\\\/'\xE0\xE8\xE9\xF9\xF2\xEC\x27-]*\])?$/
```